# Undesired anonymous function after compile

Tags: clojurescript

I'm writing an interface layer with pure functions in ClojureScript, but I'm getting undesired results after compile. Simple parameterized functions work fine. The example:

```
(defn rev [s]
  (.. s (split "") (reverse) (join "")))
```

... will successfully generate `function rev(s){return s.split("").reverse().join(""); }`, while, with more complex parameters, like `[s a & [b]]`, or with parametric polimorphism, it generates an anonymous function:

```
(defn substr
  ([s a b]
    (.. s (substr a b)))
  ([s a]
    (.. s (substr a))))
```

... generates: `function (s,a,b){ switch(arguments.length){ case 2: return substr__2.call(this,s,a); case 3: return substr__3.call(this,s,a,b); } throw(new Error('Invalid arity: ' + arguments.length)); }`.

It doesn't even work with `(def substr (fn ...` instead. How can I force a function to be named with `defn`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `^:export` on your function if you are going to be calling it from javascript.

```
(defn ^:export substr
  ([s a b]
    (.. s (substr a b)))
  ([s a]
    (.. s (substr a))))
```

The compiler should then generate the name so that you can call it from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by exporting the function to the `Window` global object, of JavaScript:

```
(aset js/window "substr" stdlib.string/substr)
```